# Print expression and also echo it

Tags: python, eval, preprocessor

I mean to define a function `print_echo` that replaces `print`, such that in addition to printing the result of an expression it prints the expression itself.

If I simply pass the expression as a string and use `eval` inside `print_echo`, it will not know any variable local to the caller function.
My current code is

```
def print_echo( expr ) :
    result = eval( expr )
    print( expr + ' => ' + str( result ) + ' ' + str( type( result ) ) )
    return
```

But when using

```
def my_func( params ) :
    a = 2
    print_echo( "a" )
```

I get (no surprise)

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I mean to get

```
    a => 2 <type 'int'>
```

I conceived two ways of working around this.

1. Use a Python like alternative for C preprocessor macros. 
   Something like [C Preprocessor Macro equivalent for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491714/c-preprocessor-macro-equivalent-for-python)
2. Pass all local variables to print_echo.
   Something like [Passing all arguments of a function to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136915/passing-all-arguments-of-a-function-to-another-function)

Since I find inconvenient aspects for each of the two,
**Is there any alternative to these?**

Note that expr is a generic expression, not necessarily the name of a variable.

Comment: I think i understand, but can you provide a toy example to illustrate desired input and output?

Comment: @Chris_Rands is right. Give us some examples to better understand. Based on what I understood, traceback may help.. See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553524/2895956

Comment: @Chris_Rands - I posted from a mobile, so it was hard to format and add code I had in my PC. Now I am completing.

Comment: @SujayKumar - I do not see clearly how your link would help here.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. For me this works as you expect. What Python version are you using? (edit: it works for me for both Python 2.7 and 3.5)

Comment: @mkrieger1 - It worked because, as I posted it, `a` was a global variable. I now edited to make it local, I guess if you try the current version it will show you the error.

Answer (score 2):

[`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) only takes the global namespace, and the namespace local to where it is called, into account.

In your case, you need the namespace of where `print_echo` is called (i.e., the "parent" namespace of where `eval` is called) as the local namespace, which you can get by using the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=locals#types-and-members) module and pass to `eval` as an argument.

```
import inspect

def print_echo(expr):
    outer_locals = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
    result = eval(expr, globals(), outer_locals)
    print(expr, '=>', result, type(result))

a = 2
print_echo('a')

def f():
    b = 3
    print_echo('b')

f()
```

Python 3 output:

```
a => 2 <class 'int'>
b => 3 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: It would be better to use the outer frame's globals (`f_globals`) and not those of `print_echo` (which just so happen to be the same in your example).

Comment: @Dunes You mean replacing `globals()` by `f_back.f_globals`?

Answer (score 0):

Important Note: There can be more error handling to this case.
For more info, you can see **inspect** and explore it further.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html

```
import inspect

# NOTE: this only prints the local variables to the function
def print_echo( *expr ) :

    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back # see the previous frame and what all variable it's previous caller knows
    values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)[3]
    print values # just to understand what it is, remove it later
    for e in expr:
        try:
            result = values[e]
        except KeyError:
            eval(e) # see the globally defined variables, if not found local to previous function.
        print( str(e) + ' => ' + str( result ) + ' ' + str( type( result ) ) )
```